# jQuery this.remove() -vs.- $('#id').remove() in Internet Explorer (IE 9+)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Why is it that `this.remove()` doesn't work in IE9+?

```
<input type="button" value="Next1" id="nextButton1">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Next2" id="nextButton2">

$('#nextButton1').on('click', function() {
   this.remove(); // works in all browsers but IE9+
});

$('#nextButton2').on('click', function() {
   $('#nextButton2').remove(); //works in all browsers
});
```

[JSFiddle live version](http://jsfiddle.net/pemoke/6yFgz/)

Comment: try $(this).remove()

Comment: You seem to assume that `this` is a jQuery object. It is not. [**Please read the jQuery tutorial**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/): *"In addition to the event object, the event handling function also has access to the DOM element that the handler was bound to via the keyword `this`. To turn the DOM element into a jQuery object that we can use jQuery methods on, we simply do `$( this )`, often following this idiom: `var element = $( this );`"*

Comment: Shim: `if (!HTMLElement.prototype.remove) HTMLElement.prototype.remove = function() { return this.parentNode.removeChild(this) };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're using the `ChildNode.remove()` method which is not supported by all browsers.

```
this ---> refers to a node. //WARNING: This is an experimental technology
```

jQuery's `.remove()` method, however is cross-browser and so to use it you have to wrap `this` in `$(...)` like this:

```
$(this).remove();
```

[**ChildNode.remove() Browser Compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove)

`this.remove()` is supported by the following desktop browsers:

```
- Chrome 23+
- Firefox 23+
- Opera 10+
- Safari 7+
```

Comment: What if you want to remove only a class of this?  i.e. $(this.link).remove(); ?? whereby anything with the class "link" would be removed?

Comment: How about `$('.link').remove()`? Perhaps you would like to ask a full question so we know the context. .... If the context is `this` then try `$(this).filter('.link').remove()`

Answer (score 3):

Wrap `this` in jQuery:

```
$('#nextButton1').on('click', function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked why, so here's why:

Within the context of a jQuery event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element reference that jQuery stores for the element that you are currently handling events for. Because the `.remove()` function you are intending to use is a jQuery [member function](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/), and not a native DOM browser function, it does not work as expected.

However, if you wrap the DOM reference inside of `$()` or `jQuery()`, so it becomes `$(this)` instead of `this`, the `$` or `jQuery` function takes the DOM reference as a parameter and returns a jQuery reference, which is then capable of having jQuery member functions invoked on it.

You can always pass your DOM references to jQuery and get jQuery references back

E.g.

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
$(test).remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2h45Y/

Comment: _"Because .remove() is a jQuery member function, and not a native DOM browser function, it does not work."_ But it does work in all browsers except IE.

Comment: @j08691 Edited for clarity.